# B+ tree insertion on non-key search field

Tags: database, search, b-tree

I am trying to answer the following question but I am confused on the subject of B+ trees.  Below is the question:

Is it possible to define an insertion algorithm for a B+ tree on a non-key search field? If yes, explain by showing insertions with appropriate search values (you need not define the algorithm in formal terms). If not, provide necessary justification.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The key values are not given? How could you insert an item into the tree, then?! What are you supposed to write to the memory location that would normally store the key at?

Comment: i dont either thats why I am looking for help.  My teacher gave me this question and I am lost..think he was high